# Intellij: Disable duplicate for @Deprecated files

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a few classes that are deprecated, the new version of those classes have similar logic. So now intellij is showing that a lot of the code are duplicated. Should I just remove the deprecated class from the code base? or is there a way to disable duplicated code check if the class is marked as deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly remove the deprecated files, if they are not used - that would be best. If you need to keep them for now, you can add

```java
@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
```

Over the methods or classes that are giving you warnings.